# Access Facebook Graph API in Python, Access Token usage

Tags: facebook, python-2.7, api, facebook-graph-api

I'm new to Python, and have been using different tutorials/guides to build a program for getting data from a Facebook page, and write it into an AzureSQL database. In the Facebook Developer page I've set up an app, and created the AppID and AppSecret.

Here's the relevant part of the code I think the issue is with:

```
#create authenticated post URL
def create_post_url(graph_url, APP_ID, APP_SECRET):
    post_args = "/posts/?key=value&access_token=" + APP_ID + "|" + APP_SECRET
    post_url = graph_url + post_args

    return post_url

#render graph url call to JSON
def render_to_json(graph_url):
    web_response = urllib2.urlopen(graph_url)
    readable_page = web_response.read()
    json_data = json.loads(readable_page)

    return json_data    

def main():
    #define facebook app secret and app id
    APP_SECRET = "xyz"
    APP_ID = "abc"

    #define page username
    pagelist = ["porsche"]
    graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/"
```

In the Facebook Graph API Explorer, running a GET request will work great and return data.

[Facebook Graph API Explorer results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtRdF.png)

Howerver if I run my code in the CLI, the resulting error is as follows:

```
    [vagrant@localhost SomeAnalysis]$ python src/collectors/facebook/facebookScaper.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/collectors/facebook/facebookScaper.py", line 92, in <module>
    main() 
  File "src/collectors/facebook/facebookScaper.py", line 56, in main
    json_fbpage = render_to_json(current_page)
  File "src/collectors/facebook/facebookScaper.py", line 25, in render_to_json
    web_response = urllib2.urlopen(graph_url)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 154, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 437, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 550, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 475, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 558, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
```

I've been checking SO and have found similar posts but none explain how to use the Access Token. I've tried changing the part in the URL formation with APP_ID and APP_SECRET to just using the long ACCESS_TOKEN from the Graph API Explorer but that yields the same 400 error.

Any help is appreciated.

/K

Comment: Go check the response body, it should contain a human-readable error message.

Comment: Hi @CBroe. Thanks for replying. When you say 'response body', are you referring to the output in the Graph API Explorer..?

Comment: Do you _have_ the problem in GAE ...? No, so why would I tell you to go look for error messages _there_ ... You are making an HTTP request in your python code, and the response consists of a head and body. So go research how to get access to the response body with the framework you are using.